# Reasons for extremely high number density of galaxies at low redshift

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, sky-survey

I am currently analyzing the SDSS data especially in the extremely low redshift area, in order to measure the cosmological statistics. What I mean by extremely low is z<0.1. One peculiarity that I noticed was a sharp peak of number density in about z~0.02, z~0.08.

I reckon that it may be due to the CFA2 great wall, and am quite curious of whether this could possibly bias the mean number density of galaxies(or matter) as a function of redshift. Is there a reason for such massive peak of number density? Would it be plausible to measure the cosmological statistics within the low redshift regime? Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I added the plot so as to clarify my question. I have used the raw data of NYU-VAGC/LSS catalog (Blanton et al, 2005), without making user-defined luminosity/color cuts.

[image: NYU-VAGC LSS catalog survey]

[image: Number density in Logscale]

Comment: For curiosity and in order to illustrate the point of your question: can you link to a source (preferrably paper) which shows the number of galaxies as function of distance? For what I remember galaxies at large form a "foam" like patterin in 3D space, thus being distributed homogenously on cosmic scales, thus even avaraging over the voids. But maybe that is just expression of detecting this bubble scale in the cosmos?

Comment: Following on from @planetmaker's comment, it would be useful to see what kind of "sharp peak" is actually involved, and how "massive" it is. As stated, your question is probably too impressionistic to be answered.

Comment: @PeterErwin I have added the figure that I have plotted. I hope this clarifies my question. I have also added the logscale plot too.

Comment: The bulk of this effect is due to the fact we can't see low luminosity galaxies when they are far away.